# Bower list shows the red "different" tag

Tags: npm, polymer, bower, package

When I run the Bower list command, I have the tree with some packages with the "different" tag in red color.

├── iron-dropdown#2.0.0

├── iron-fit-behavior#2.0.1

├── iron-flex-layout#2.0.0 **different**

├─┬ iron-form#2.0.0

│ ├── iron-ajax#2.0.5

│ └── polymer#2.0.2

├── iron-form-element-behavior#2.0.0 **different**

Anyone knows what does it mean?? Thanks!

**Edit:**
According to the Bower package source code:

// Check if source changed, marking as different if it did
 // We only do this for direct root dependencies that are compatible

Comment: According to the Bower package source code:

 // Check if source changed, marking as different if it did
 // We only do this for direct root dependencies that are compatible

Comment: The **different** tag comes if you put caret sign(^) in front of them in `bower.json`.